# How can i return any Data from solana smart contract to client side?

Tags: anchor, rust, anchor-client

I want data from return smart contract  so that i can use it in client side

Comment: Adding more details here would be really helpful to guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
const CreatedAccountPubkey = new anchor.web3.PublicKey("5rLPJrgrNyWZ3TwvbcJvGmV5qaJdBZ9c72dG3cCbywzW");

const Account = await program.account.data.fetch(CreatedAccountPubkey);

console.log("Authority ", Account.authority.toString());
```

This action does not consume SOL

Answer (score 0):

The answer is obviously Yes.

Could you add more details on what you want to achieve?

For example, https://solanacookbook.com/guides/get-program-accounts.html#filters

using solana web3.js you can retrieve all program accounts data stored on the chain so you can display it on your client side(say users' browser)